# How to init variable on Fragment shown using FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

Base on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43529254/fragmentstatepageradapter-returns-wrong-positions-in-getitem), how can I init variable in Fragment1 when I navigate to it. Let's say

Fragment1 has mCount(int) which I want it to be 0 every time I navigate to Fragment1.

Because in Fragment1, it will have the event that change the variable mCount.

And Fragment1 will not calling `onCreateView` if I go Fragment0 and Fragment1 back and forth.

I cannot find the way to init variable because fragment will get position 2 which is Fragment2.

Thank you in advance for any help or any suggestions.

Comment: why will it not be calling onCreateView?

Comment: It's not going to call onCreateView on Fragment0 and Fragment1 when I go back and forth between two of them. It will call onCreateView of Fragment2.

Comment: I was going to tell you to send it in the Bundle when you opened Fragment1 but if it won't call onCreateView then there is no use.

Comment: See linked duplicate.  In your case, instead of using the `sendGetRequest()` method, define your method in the Fragment as `reInitCount()`, and re-initialize the count inside that method.